# How we get the GCP bucket name using data resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to create a `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` for cloudbuild trigger. Instead of hard coding the bucket name, I want to get the bucket name for cloudbuild using data resource. I don't want to hardcode my bucket name like this `bucket = var.bucket_name`.

This is how my current main.tf file looks like:

```
###
### Manage permission for google bucket
###
data "google_iam_policy" "admin" {
  binding {
    role = "var.custom_role"
    members = var.admin_member
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_policy" "policy" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.admin.policy_data
}

###
### Manage a list of Cloudbuild triggers
###
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "filename-trigger" {
  trigger_template {
    branch_name = var.branch_name
    repo_name   = var.repo_name
  }
  filename = var.file_name
}
```

Comment: How do you intend to identify the bucket if you don't know the name?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR thanks for your reply. I think I was able to figure this out.  I had to use `bucket  = "artifacts.${var.project_id}.appspot.com"` to solve the issue I was having. Closing this out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my issue:

```
###
### Manage permission for google bucket
###
data "google_iam_policy" "admin" {
  binding {
    role = "var.custom_role"
    members = var.admin_member
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_policy" "policy" {
  bucket  = "artifacts.${var.project_id}.appspot.com"
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.admin.policy_data
}

###
### Manage a list of Cloudbuild triggers
###
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "filename-trigger" {
  trigger_template {
    branch_name = var.branch_name
    repo_name   = var.repo_name
  }
  filename = var.file_name
}
```